# Script using TimeShift Function in a JSR223 PreProcessor throws Invalid octal number error on some iterations only

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

In a JSR223 PreProcessor I am trying to generate some random dates (within some boundaries) so that I may use them in a HTTP Request.

I wrote the following code using the JMeter [timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function :

```
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,${__time(yyyy-MM-dd,)},P${__Random(0,90)}D,,entryDate)};
log.info("entryDate " + "${entryDate}");
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,${entryDate},P${__Random(0,90)}D,,exitDate)};
log.info("exitDate " + "${exitDate}");
```

For testing purposes I just use 1 thread and let it run in a loop for 120 seconds. The problem is that when the code executes, on some iterations it is able to print the randomly calculated dates as I want (screenshot attached) and on some iterations it throws the error below.

Error example:

```
2023-01-04 21:01:31,903 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script472.groovy: 1: Invalid octal number @ line 1, column 9 @ line 1, column 9.
   2023-02-08;
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:978) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:561) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script472.groovy: 1: Invalid octal number @ line 1, column 9 @ line 1, column 9.
   2023-02-08;
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:292) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:148) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.collectSyntaxError(AstBuilder.java:4375) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.createParsingFailedException(AstBuilder.java:4358) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.convertException(AstBuilder.java:261) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.buildCST(AstBuilder.java:235) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.buildAST(AstBuilder.java:269) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.Antlr4ParserPlugin.buildAST(Antlr4ParserPlugin.java:58) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.buildAST(SourceUnit.java:256) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.buildASTs(CompilationUnit.java:666) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:632) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:314) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:257) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:336) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:153) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    ... 8 more
```

I would appreciate some help to understand why this is happening and how I may avoid it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid it you should stop using JMeter Functions and/or variables inside JSR223 Test Elements.

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. **Instead use script parameters**.

[image]

So you can put your functions into "Parameters" section and use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for reading the generated dates as JMeter Variables syntax clashes with [Groovy strings interpolation feature](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: Thanks! This removed the error, but I noticed that I can only generate random dates on each iteration only if I don't check the "Cache compiled script if available" checkbox, otherwise if I check it, the user 0 will always have the same entryDate and exitDate values on every loop. In your screenshot I see you have the option checked and yet you seem to get new random dates on each iteration. Can you please tell me why that is?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to use vars.get when printing in the JSR223 element instead of printing out the jmeter variable. :D